# How is this number expressed as a multiple of 2^-22*(1/10)? How is that derived?

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal, bit-manipulation, bit

I was refreshing on binary and floats and I run into the following example:
0.1 is represented as: `0.0001100110011001100110011[0011]` with the part in the brackets repeating.
If we round up this representation we get:
`x = 0.00011001100110011001101` (0.10000002384185791015625 in decimal).

The difference x-0.1 has the binary representation:
`0.0000000000000000000000000[1100]` which is (0.00000002384185791015625 in decimal).
Now how can this value be expressed as a fraction of `2^x* 1/10`?
I have read that it is basically `2^-22`*(1/10) but I can't see how we can derive this. Any help?
Note: The numbers are rounded to 23 bits (but the 1 in the x-0.1 example is in the 25th)

**Update:**
My question is not how 1/10 is represented.
But how from the bit string `0.0000000000000000000000000[1100]` we can express it in a "human" format i.e. in decimal. In this case that it was `2^-22*(1/10)`

Comment: interesting question really you cant find a detailed answer [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)

Comment: `0.1 is represented as: 0.0001100110011001100110011[0011]`. If you look at it a bit more closely, you can see it's the same as `0.0[0011]`. Then observe that `0.00[0011]b == 0.0[0011]b / (2^1)` and `0.000[0011]b ==  0.0[0011]b / (2^2)` and so on.

Comment: @n.m.:Sorry what do you mean by the notation b in the `[0011]b`? And the rest is divide by (2^1)?

Comment: @n.m:What is the notation here:`0.00[0011]b == 0.0[0011]b / (2^1)` I don't understand the `b / (2^1)` part

Comment: b is just a symbol that says "the preceding number is binary".

Answer (score 0):

Use the property that an `n` digit binary number , repeated, has the value of the

```
pattern *= (1 << BitWidth)/ ((1 << BitWidth) - 1);
```

The proceed to simplify the fraction.

```
unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  if (b == 0)
    return a;
  else
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

// Print result & return NULL on success, else point to problem in input.    
const char *Cratylus_s(const char *src) {

  // parse the input
  const char *s = src;
  while (*s == '0')
    s++;
  if (*s != '.') {
    return s;
  }
  s++;
  const char *rp = s;  // radix point
  while (*s == '0')
    s++;
  int offset = s - rp;
  if (*s != '[') {
    return s;
  }
  s++;
  unsigned bin = 0;
  unsigned pow2 = 0;
  while (*s == '0' || *s == '1') {
    bin = bin * 2 + *s - '0';
    pow2++;
    s++;
  }
  if (*s != ']' || *++s != '\0') {
    return s;
  }

  // multiply `bin` by (1 << pow2)/((1 << pow2 - 1)
  unsigned num = bin * (1 << pow2);
  unsigned den = (1 << pow2) - 1;
  const char *format = "2^%d*(%u/%u)\n";
  printf(format, offset + pow2, num, den); // 2^29*(192/15)

  // simplify
  unsigned common = gcd(num, den);
  num /= common;
  den /= common;
  printf(format, offset + pow2, num, den); // 2^29*(64/5)

  // find powers of 10
  for (unsigned d = den; d && d % 5 == 0; d /= 5) {
    num *= 2;
    den *= 2;
  }

  // find powers of 2
  for (unsigned n = num; n && n % 2 == 0; n /= 2) {
    num /= 2;
    offset--;
  }
  printf(format, offset + pow2, num, den); // 2^-22*(1/10)
  return NULL;

}

void Cratylus_test(const char *s) {
  printf("'%s'\n", s);
  const char *t = Cratylus_s(s);
  printf("'%s'\n", t ? t : "OK");
}

int main(void) {
  Cratylus_test("0.0000000000000000000000000[1100]");
  Cratylus_test("0.000000000000000[0110]");
  return 0;
}

'0.0000000000000000000000000[1100]'
2^29*(192/15)
2^29*(64/5)
2^22*(1/10)
'OK'
'0.000000000000000[0110]'
2^19*(96/15)
2^19*(32/5)
2^13*(1/10)
'OK'
```